# PHP 5.5.x libphp5.so size

Tags: php

Using yum to install latest php for FC17 and I get php 5.4.17 and its libphp5.so size is just under 400,000 but it includes numerous modules I do not need/use.

I decided to roll my own and I downloaded php 5.5.3 and compiled successfully but the libphp.so is now over 1,400,000 even though I've disabled numerous extensions included with the yum installed version.

I've double checked my configure statement (see below).  I've done this before without issue.

Any explanation?

```
'./configure' \
'--build=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' \
'--host=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' \
'--program-prefix=' \
'--prefix=/usr' \
'--exec-prefix=/usr' \
'--bindir=/usr/bin' \
'--sbindir=/usr/sbin' \
'--sysconfdir=/etc' \
'--datadir=/usr/share' \
'--includedir=/usr/include' \
'--libdir=/usr/lib' \
'--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' \
'--localstatedir=/var' \
'--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' \
'--mandir=/usr/share/man' \
'--infodir=/usr/share/info' \
'--cache-file=../config.cache' \
'--with-libdir=lib' \
'--with-config-file-path=/etc' \
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' \
'--disable-debug' \
'--disable-libxml' \
'--with-pic' \
'--disable-rpath' \
'--without-pear' \
'--with-mcrypt' \
'--without-iconv' \
'--with-freetype-dir=/usr' \
'--with-png-dir=/usr' \
'--with-xpm-dir=/usr' \
'--without-gd' \
'--with-t1lib=/usr' \
'--without-gdbm' \
'--with-gettext' \
'--without-gmp' \
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' \
'--with-pcre-regex=/usr' \
'--with-zlib' \
'--with-layout=GNU' \
'--enable-exif' \
'--without-mysql' \
'--with-mysqli' \
'--disable-dom' \
'--disable-dba' \
'--without-unixODBC' \
'--disable-pdo' \
'--disable-xmlreader' \
'--disable-xmlwriter' \
'--without-sqlite3' \
'--disable-phar' \
'--disable-fileinfo' \
'--without-pspell' \
'--disable-wddx' \
'--disable-posix' \
'--disable-sysvmsg' \
'--disable-sysvshm' \
'--disable-sysvsem' \
'--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' \
'--enable-opcache=no' \
'--disable-xml' \
'--disable-simplexml'
```

Comment: Why are you so concerned about the size of the executable of two completely different versions of a program?

Comment: Unless you build `5.4.17`, there's nothing to compare to, and as deceze says why are you even thinking about the size of the executable? Size has no direct relation with e.g. performance.

Comment: 5.5 includes the OpCache as a default module, which is a fairly significant feature that isn't in 5.4. Not sure whether it would account for the difference, but as others have said, I wouldn't worry about it.